# What equipment do I need to start brewing into 5L kegs?

Tags: equipment, kegging

I have just bought a 5L kegerator system for my office & would like to start bringing my homebrew in.

What do I need to get started?  Can I re-use purchased 5L kegs or are there any retailers around that sell empties?

Comment: Are you hiring?

Comment: Lukers...also google tap-a-draft as an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Equipment**

- 5L kegs (will need 4x to brew a 20L batch)
- 2-way bungs (1x for each keg)
- 1/3 cup sugar (for priming)
- Secondary vessel / Bottling bucket

**Process**

1. Ferment primary brew as per usual
2. Clean kegs with warm water and gentle bleach & sterilise kegs as would bottles
3. Rack brew onto secondary / bucket with 1/3 cup sugar
4. Fill kegs to 25mm short of the top & seal with 2-way bung (may need water for lubrication)
5. Store kegs as if they were bottles (e.g. 2 weeks at room temp)
6. Enjoy

Directions taken from [minikeg.net.au](http://minikeg.net.au/cms.php?id_cms=6&temp=6).

Comment: Why are you priming kegs in step 5 when you added sugar in step 3?

Comment: Poor choice of words on my part.

Answer (score 3):

There is some good information here on reusing them also: http://forum.northernbrewer.com/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=90461&start=0

Answer (score 1):

You can buy new or used kegs, but keep in mind that mini kegs are usually harder to find than full size cornies, and can thus be 2-3 times more expensive.

Details about usage (priming, tapping, cleaning, sanitizing, etc.) are given [here](http://www.brewery.org/library/mini112994.html).  If you buy used, it's a good idea to ensure that it's been pressure tested before you buy, and pick up some spare o-rings.